# In the THREE.js documentation, it says using Group is better than Object3d but why?

Tags: object, three.js

It says in the documentation for Object3d:

> Note that this can be used for grouping objects via the .add( object ) method which adds the object as a child, however it is better to use Group for this.

But **why** is it better to use Group?

Comment: Because: "_This is almost identical to an Object3D. It's purpose is to make working with groups of objects syntactically clearer_".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You may use `THREE.Group` or `THREE.Object3D` to hold a collection of objects.

It is "better" to use `THREE.Group` only in the sense that

(1) it may make your code more readable, and

(2) the use of `THREE.Group` is a *hint* to the renderer that the object itself is not renderable.

```
object instanceof THREE.Object3D; // object could be renderable (e.g., a THREE.Mesh)

object instanceof THREE.Group; // object, itself, is not renderable
```

three.js r.84

Comment: That's what I assumed. And thank you for pointing out the relevant lines.  And of course, the highly relevant point #1, which was my inital assumption.

Comment: is it a problem to overwrite the "type" field of a group with a custom one? I know that we have the "userData" object, just curious whether that would have an impact inside three and how objects are handled

Comment: I would advise you to use the `userData` property to avoid future breakage.

Comment: I have a large number of meshes in my scene, some are assets like furnitures for instance, few of them are walls and ground. I want to be able to quickly hide/show only the assets. So would it be faster to place all assets inside a ground and set the "group.visible=false", or iterating all assets and do "asset.visible=false"? Or is it the same? Thanks

Comment: @Philippe I expect you have done an experiment and answered your question yourself, but see https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Layers.